How can I determine the Vulkan synchronization scopes for pipeline barriers?
The Vulkan spec introduces synchronization scopes in section 6 in a bit of an abstract way. It refers to a "set of operations" being contained in a synchronization scope. How can I determine which operations are in a synchronization scope, especially for determining appropriate vkPipelineStageFlags in a pipeline barrier?
For example, imagine the common case of a deferred renderer with two render passes. The first render pass writes to the G-buffer and the second pass reads from the G-buffer to, e.g., computing lighting. Between the various draw calls in these passes we should insert a pipeline barrier that prevents the lighting render pass from reading from the G-buffer until the first pass finishes writing to the G-buffer. Intuitively, there should be two synchronization scopes and they should contain all the draw commands in the first and second passes, respectively.
My question is: is this consistent with the Vulkan spec, i.e. that all commands in a render pass describe the synchronization scope, or is there a more concrete way of determining these scopes? Which commands are affected by the source and destination vkPipelineStageFlags?
